# Unable to add a Repository

Tags: software-installation, add-apt-repository

So I am trying to add a ppa and when using

```
add-apt-repository
```

I get

```
apt-add-repository: command not found
```

I tried to do

```
sudo apt-get Install apt-add-repository
```

and there is no file to download

I need to install this ppa
Thanks in advance

Comment: No this is how to indtall add-apt-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

You may also need to run either

```
sudo apt-get install python3-software-properties
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Hope that helps.